# Access 2010 Web Browser Control Zoom Images

Tags: zooming, jpeg, ms-access-2010

I have a web browser on a form that displays a JPEG image that is on the Internet.  A different image for each record.

Is there any way to set zooming using the URL or the web browser control itself?

I need to display a thumbnail version of the full image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it works for me in Access 2010.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
''Zoom to 25%
    Me.WebBrowser0.Object.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, _
        OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, CLng(25), vbNull
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
''Navigate image
    Me.WebBrowser0.Object.Navigate "http://www.ibiblio.org/wm/rh/img/january.jpg"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer I'm using the WebBrowserControl not the WebBrowser object.

Comment: You added a Microsoft Webbrowser control to a form, is that correct? That is what I did, and that is code that I tested. The webbrowser control contains a webbrowser object.

Comment: I'm using the built-in WebBrowserControl in Microsoft Access 2010.  This is not selected via the ActiveX controls but is a control available straightaway in the toolbox.

Comment: Okay, I have just tested with the webbrowser control from the toolbar in a fresh database, you can use the above but you need to add `Object` for the zoom as well as the navigate. The reason I show the navigate code is that you cannot run zoom until the site / image is loaded.